# CSS dynamically position footer (sticky footer problem)

Tags: css, position, footer, sticky-footer

I am trying to achieve the same effect the sticky footer does, but I have a problem which does not appear in any tutorial or question asked here: my footer's height is also dynamic.

I have some news items in my footer, so that the height of the footer changes according to the length of those news items.
Obviously, I want the footer to be positioned absolute to the bottom of the page when the content's height is smaller than the browser's view-port, and relative to the content when its height is higher than the actual view-port.

Currently I implemented this successfully in jQuery, but I would like a CSS-only method (if any) because some users keep JavaScript disabled in their browsers.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

My code is pretty much usual: I have a `<header>`, an `<aside>`, a `<section>` and a `<footer>` in my `<body>` tag.
In jQuery, I pretty much compare the sum of the heights of these elements (without the footer) to the browser view-port. If the value is greater, I add a `position:relative` to the footer, else I add a `position:absolute; bottom:0` to it.

Comment: Can we see your code, or do we have to guess? :D

Answer (score 1):

CSS can do some of it by using `bottom:0; position:fixed;` however this is not supported by IE6 and maybe 7. I would suggest using the CSS method in tandem with the jQuery solution so all your users will have a similar experience.

Comment: It doesn't help. I need a sticky footer behaviour, not a fixed one.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the difference?  Can you give an example?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I want the footer to be position dynamically according to the content, similarly to the sticky footer.